# is there a concurrent restful api call framework?

Tags: rest, rpc

our project has web,phone clients.

so between database and clients,we want to add API layer.

which kind of API is better?

i know there is a concurrent RPC framework named YAR in php.

is there a concurrent framework for rest api?

Comment: What is the language used at server end?

Comment: we have c, ruby and php developers.so these three languages are ok